# Local Storage multiple key storage

Tags: javascript, html, api, local-storage

I was wondering if I can by any chance store more than one key on localStorage ? For instance :

```
localStorage.setItem("a_key", a_value);
localStorage.setItem("another_key", another_value);
```

Is it possible to do so ? If not what do you advise I shall do as a workaround that, because I need to have two keys or variables stored on the clients side ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But why not giving it a try yourself? Just use your browser's debug console.

Comment: @PedroFerreira I tried once but it didn't work, perhaps I must have had an error :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can store multiple key/value pairs in local storage (and session storage). From the [web storage spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) (emphasis added):

> Each Storage object provides access to a **list of key/value pairs**,
> which are sometimes called items. Keys are strings. Any string
> (including the empty string) is a valid key. Values are similarly
> strings.
>
> ...
>
> The length attribute must return the **number of key/value pairs**
> currently present in the list associated with the object.

Comment: One question though, if I'll use this polyfill :  https://gist.github.com/2597130 , will I be able to store an abject and retrieve it the same ? Because I'm trying to and when I get the object back it cones an array of two objects ...

Comment: @Roland - That polyfill should work fine. The `getItem` method should return the value associated with the key provided. The polyfill I tend to use is [this one](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/), but both should behave in the same way. Note that no polyfills for web storage are perfect however... they don't fire the storage events that the native API does. If you are relying on those, you will only really be able to support the modern browsers.

Comment: I see, I know that only modern browsers support Local Storage, but that polyfill falls back to cookies if the storage is not available. Well, I know it should behave the same, but I still get something else when fetching the data. What I'm storing is : `var data = { current_page: 2, total_pages: 4 }` and what I get is : `[object Object]`, why would that happen ?

Comment: Ahh I see. That happens because local and session storage can only store strings. When you try to store an object, it gets converted to a string (which is "[object Object]"). You need to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your object before storing it: `localStorage.setItem("someKey", JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: Oh yeah... looks like it does. Are you sure it was using the polyfill when you got that? The native methods don't automatically stringify the data, so my guess would be that you were using a browser with native local storage support.

Comment: I got it working now, indeed the polyfill wasn't working, so I had to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: By the way guys, I wrote (https://github.com/andresgallo/truStorage/blob/master/truStorage.js)... a pollyfill that lets you write and read objects, arrays and more into local storage.  It also let you access and make changes into the nested keys in your objects. Best part is... its smaller than all polyfills I have seen